# Why isn't the second whole note's accidental natural?

Tags: theory, notation

[image]

Above is a staff. After the third bar, why isn't the second C either sharp or natural?

Comment: I think you don't understand key signatures properly. This might help you in undertanding them: http://www.musictheory.net/lessons/24 .

Comment: Thanks so much, I really hate reading wiki, for it covers so many unnecessary stuffs. This is highly encouraged.

Comment: You can find many other topics and resources on that site.

Comment: The notation in the question is correct. However, it would be foolish not to reinforce it with cautionary accidentals.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Accidentals (sharps, flats or naturals) only change notes until the end of the bar they are in. So, the C# above doesn't affect the C in the next bar. However, flats or sharps in [key-signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_signature) affect all notes in the music, for instance the Bb and Eb above, unless "overruled" by another accidental, for example the B [natural](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sign) above.

Comment: I just want to add although it is unnecessary, most composers would put a natural sign next to the C as a reminder to the musician to play a C instead of a C#.

Comment: @ Dom - yes, they do, and I feel it's clogging up the staves. It's not necessary, the bar line cancels anyway. Take it further, if there's another C in the next bar, should the writer remind us again, after all, it's another bar...

Comment: So what you r saying is, there is a natural sign before the first c because there is no bar before it to cancel flat signatures?

Comment: Still doesn't explain my question. Why isn't it a flat c?

Comment: There's no flat in front of the C or Cb in the key signature. So, nothing to make it flat.

Comment: I think you might be getting the signs for sharps, flats and naturals mixed up.

Comment: @Dom Often it's not the composer but the editor who adds the superfluous accidentals.